# Cannot enter psql command "FATAL: the database system is starting up"

Tags: postgresql, crash

I cannot login into postgresql server using  `psql` command (to create / update / delete table) because some sort of error like below.

the command :

```
[root@Server-Database pg_log]# su postgres
bash-4.1$ psql
psql: FATAL:  the database system is starting up
bash-4.1$
```

I am using postgresql 9.2 in CentOS 6.3

here is log file

```
[root@Server-Database pg_log]# tail -f postgresql-Mon.log
FATAL:  the database system is starting up
FATAL:  the database system is starting up
FATAL:  the database system is starting up
FATAL:  the database system is starting up
....
```

startup log :

```
[root@Server-Database data]# tail -f /var/lib/pgsql/9.2/pgstartup.log
could not write to log file: No space left on device
could not write to log file: No space left on device
could not write FATAL:  lock file "postmaster.pid" already exists
HINT:  Is another postmaster (PID 5872) running in data directory "/var/lib/pgsql/9.2/data"?
```

for information, this server have a crash one day ago, because empty hdd space, this is the space after crash solving :

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_serverdatabas-lv_root
                      439G  408G  8.5G  98% /
```

server successfully restarted (look command below), but things still not resolved, I cannot enter psql command

```
[root@Server-Database data]# /etc/init.d/postgresql-9.2 restart
Stopping postgresql-9.2 service:                           [  OK  ]
Starting postgresql-9.2 service:                           [  OK  ]
```

Comment: Try to make a little extra space because if you only have 2% left, you're in for trouble. Have a look here on how to get rid of this pid: http://superuser.com/questions/553045/fatal-lock-file-postmaster-pid-already-exists

Answer (score 1):

There is no more space on the device:

could not write to log file: No space left on device

Check it with df and make some space